# Delete matching lines in two tab delimited files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 2 tab delimited files

```
A 2
A 5
B 4
B 5
C 10
```

and

```
A 2
A 5
B 5
```

I want to delete the lines in file1 that are in file2 so that the output is:

```
B 4
C 10
```

I have tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};!c[$1$2] > 0' file2 file1 > file3
```

but it deletes more lines than expected.

```
1026997259 file1 
   1787919 file2 
1023608359 file3
```

How can I modify this code, so that:

I have 2 tab delimited files

```
A 2 3
A 5 4
B 4 5
B 5 5
C 10 12
```

and

```
A 2 5
A 5 4
B 5 3 
F 6 7
```

Based only in the 1st and 2nd columns, I want to grab the lines in file1 that are also in file2 so that the output is:

```
B 5 5
C 10 12
```

Comment: Heyall! I thought of posting a new question but it's just a modification of this one. How can I modify the code so that I can grab the unmatching lines between the two files instead of the matching ones? Something that would work for files containing more than those two columns (see example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it - if you concatenate `ab c` and `a cb` they both become `abc` so what do you think your code is doing with `$1$2`? Use SUBSEP as intended (`$1,$2`) and change `!c[$1$2] > 0` to `!(($1,$2) in c)`. Also consider whether `!c[$1$2] > 0` means `!(c[$1$2] > 0)` or `(!c[$1$2]) > 0`. I'd never write the former code so idk for sure, I'd always write it with parens as I intended it to be parsed. So do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1,$2];next} !(($1,$2) in c)' file2 file1
```

Or just use `$0` instead of `$1,$2`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$0];next} !($0 in c)' file2 file1
```

Comment: Got it! For awk 'NR==FNR{c[$0];next} !($0 in c)' file2 file1, do I have to add BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} and or SUBSEP="\t"? It's printing every single line from file1 in file 3.

Comment: I ask because I'm still getting the wrong number of lines deleted from file1. 1026997259 file1, 1787919 file2,1025209759 file3.

Comment: No, given what you have told us so far and input as shown in your question you don't have to add or change anything and the command I posted will do exactly what you asked for. If it doesn't then you're doing something wrong or your input doesn't actually look like the sample you posted and then you'd need to investigate further and post the right input if you need help.

Comment: Yeah. I figured there was something wrong with the input files. One of then was corrupted. Yes. It works! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to use `grep` command?

```
grep -vf file2 file1
```

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't :/ It doesn't delete any lines.

Comment: I have just tested it on files with tabs and it works just fine :)

Comment: See my comment above. Yes this works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the matching lines in the two files are identical, and the two files are sorted in the same order, then **comm**(1) can do the trick:

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

It prints out lines that are only in the first file (unless `-1` is given), lines that are only in the second file (unless `-2`), and lines that are in both files (unless `-3`).  If you leave more than one option enabled then they will be printed in multiple (tab-separated) columns.